# what the minimal amount of bytes that required to change for skip function

Tags: elf

Consider that you get an ELF that has a segmentation fault in a function that names `print_debug.`
Since that function not relevant for the program you want to "cancel" the function manually by using Hexedit.

the size of the function is 100 bytes.

what the minimal amount of byte that required to change for fixing the file?

the answers:

- 1
- 2
- 99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The answers

The answer is: it *depends* on the instruction set.

On `i*86` and `x86_64` you can use a single-byte `RET`, but on a typical RISC machine you would need 4 bytes, and on `ARM` in Thumb mode you will need 2 (I think).